# Does the phrase がんばする makes sense?

Tags: grammar

Person A: 頑張って{がんばって}！

Person B: ありがとう！**がんばする**！

Is it right to use that last phrase by person B?

Comment: Why do you assume it to be a "suru-verb"? Just a guess?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Yeah just a guess. From what I understand, "suru" is "to do", which I then interpret it as "I'll do my best".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it right to use that last phrase by person B?

The answer can be yes or no. がんばする is understandable, but is far from standard. You should avoid using it if you are still learning how to write standard and correct Japanese sentences. Of course the correct form is がんばる, which is a godan verb.

That being said, if you really saw ガンバする said by a native speaker in an online chat or such, it's probably not a typo, either. Native speakers often play on words and use funny and loose expressions knowing they're not standard, and ガンバする is one of such examples. Actually ガンバする is not entirely baseless because "ガンバ!" on its own is recognized as a (bit outdated) expression meaning "hang in there!" or "do your best!" (hence the name [Gamba Osaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamba_Osaka)). ガンバする is not common enough to be called an established slangy verb, but you can easily find real examples of it with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 3):

頑張って is the te-form of the verb 頑張る. To the best of my knowledge 頑張 on its own is not a real word and so could not form a する verb.

Although, curiously, I did find a handful of uses of 頑張する on Google, but I'm sure it's not standard. Maybe a native speaker can comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

My Japanese is pretty minimal but after living there (Nagoya) for a couple of years my instinct would be to say 頑張ります (がんばります)!

This link has is really useful if you haven't found it already:
http://wiredinjapan.blogspot.com/2009/03/do-your-best-ganbatte.html

頑張ってね！